# Como alterar valores no eixo y

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como eu altero os valores do eixo y para 0,5,10,15,20?

```
# Dados da produção da aquicultura 2013-2019
producao_aquicultura = 
  structure(list(Valor = c(19350491, 22082777, 21063695, 20828670, 20941404, 
                           14202340, 15215778), Ano = c("2013", "2014", "2015", 
                                                        "2016", "2017", "2018", 
                                                        "2019")), 
            row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Gera o gráfico de barra
ggplot(producao_aquicultura, aes(x=Ano, y=Valor)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous("Milhões de toneladas (kg)") +
  labs(title = "Produção de ostras, vieiras e mexilhões no Brasil")
```

[image: Imagem gerada pelo ggplot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu consigo ver pelo menos duas formas de fazer isso. A primeira delas é mais bruta. Basta dividir a coluna `Valor` por um milhão (`1e6`).

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Gera o gráfico de barra
ggplot(producao_aquicultura, aes(x=Ano, y=Valor/1e6)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous("Milhões de toneladas (kg)") +
    labs(title = "Produção de ostras, vieiras e mexilhões no Brasil")
```

[image]

A segunda forma é usar a função `label_number` do pacote `scales`. Nesse caso, é preciso informar

- a acurácia do número (coloquei 1 para arredondar para unidades)
- a unidade (a letra `m` é o padrão)
- a escala de transformação dos números (no caso, `10^(-6)`)

```r
library(scales)

# Gera o gráfico de barra
ggplot(producao_aquicultura, aes(x=Ano, y=Valor)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    scale_y_continuous("Milhões de toneladas (kg)", 
                       labels = label_number(accuracy = 1, unit = "", scale = 1e-6)) +
    labs(title = "Produção de ostras, vieiras e mexilhões no Brasil")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Uau, muito bom. Solucionou o problema. Obrigado!